# Touch up my garage floor after applying epoxy coating

Tags: floor, paint, epoxy

We put RustOleum epoxy floor paint on the garage floor. There were light streaks on it when it dried. We repainted the light spots and reapplied the sparkles. It looks like its not going darken to match the rest of the floor.

What might be the reason why?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Home Improvement! A picture might be very helpful in diagnosing the problem in this case....

Answer (score 1):

The first layer dried quicker because of the moisture in the concrete. The part where you repainted was on top of the first coat and takes longer to completely dry. Hopefully, when it does, the colors will match.

Answer (score 1):

It may well be that the original coat has been affected by daylight over time so it might always look different.